# Input and formatted output for python

Tags: python

A half-life is the amount of time it takes for a substance or entity to fall to half its original value. Caffeine has a half-life of about 6 hours in humans. Given caffeine amount (in mg) as input, output the caffeine level after 6, 12, and 24 hours. Use a string formatting expression with conversion specifiers to output the caffeine amount as floating-point numbers.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
print(f'{your_value:.2f}')
Ex: If the input is:

100
the output is:

After 6 hours: 50.00 mg
After 12 hours: 25.00 mg
After 24 hours: 6.25 mg
Note: A cup of coffee has about 100 mg. A soda has about 40 mg. An "energy" drink (a misnomer) has between 100 mg and 200 mg.

```py
def caffeineLevel(caffeine_mg):
    
    half_life = 6

   
    hours = [6, 12, 24]

 
    for h in hours:
        
        caffLvl = caffeine_mg * (0.5)**(h / half_life)
    
        print(f"After {h} hours: {caffLvl:.2f}mg")
```

I tried the code above and it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO Melissa. Please tell us what happens when you run your code.

Comment: Yeah, I just ran your code and saw no issue. It seems to be working as you described on my end.

Comment: If you posted all the code you have, you have only defined the function, but not called it yet.

Comment: You didn't call the function.

Comment: You need to call the `caffeineLevel()` function first so it would work. And also you need to input an argument based on the `caffeine_mg` parameter

Comment: How are you calling your function? Have you tried `caffeineLevel(100)`? What is the result you see, and what did you expect instead? (also note that a more correct Python function name here would be `caffeine_level`, but that doesn't affect how it works of course)

Answer (score 1):

You defined the function caffeineLevel(). Try a statement like caffeineLevel(100) and it should churn out an output.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran it and it works. You just forgot to call the function that you defined.

> 

```
def caffeineLevel(caffeine_mg):

half_life = 6


hours = [6, 12, 24]


for h in hours:
    
    caffLvl = caffeine_mg * (0.5)**(h / half_life)

    print(f"After {h} hours: {caffLvl:.2f}mg")
caffeineLevel(1000)
```